# ReactJS searching Is not working with autosuggestions

Tags: reactjs, search

I am new to react and using bootstrap with react. I don't know much about react.

I tried a package for autosuggestion but now I can't submit the form for searching.
When I just use the first form(which I comment out) for searching it is worked perfectly without autosuggestion. 
How can I solve this issue?

I use Typehead for autosuggestion.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {
  Navbar,
  Badge,
  Nav,
  Container,
  containerFluid,
  Row,
  Form,
  Dropdown,
  Button,
  FormControl,
  NavDropdown,
  DropdownButton,
  ListGroup,
  ButtonGroup,
} from "react-bootstrap";
import { LinkContainer, MenuItem } from "react-router-bootstrap";
import { logout } from "../actions/userActions";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { InlineShareButtons } from "sharethis-reactjs";
import Autosuggest from "react-bootstrap-autosuggest";
import Search from "react-search";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { listProducts } from "../actions/productActions";
import { Typeahead } from "react-bootstrap-typeahead";
import Product from "../components/Product";
import InputAutoSugest from "react-input-autosugest";
import TestScreen from "../screens/TestScreen";

function Header() {
  const [singleSelections, setSingleSelections] = useState([]);

  const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList);
  const { error, loading, products } = productList;

  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
  const { userInfo } = userLogin;

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [Keyword, setKeyword] = useState("");

  let history = useHistory();

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (Keyword) {
      history.push(`/?keyword=${Keyword}`);
    } else {
      history.push(history.push(history.location.pathname));
    }
  };

  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const { cartItems } = cart;

  const logoutHandler = () => {
    dispatch(logout());
  };

  return (
    <header>
      <Container className="up_head_div">
        <Nav.Link className="upper_header">
          <h7 style={{ marginRight: 10 }}>
            <i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i> +8801792-777660{" "}
          </h7>
          <h7>
            <i className="far fa-envelope"></i> support@laksura.com.bd
          </h7>{" "}
          <h7 style={{ float: "right" }}>
            <i class="fas fa-download"></i> Download Our App Now
          </h7>
        </Nav.Link>
      </Container>

      <Navbar
        bg="transparent"
        variant="light"
        expand="lg"
        collapseOnSelect
        className="ok"
      >
        <Container>
          <LinkContainer to="/" style={{ marginRight: 60 }}>
            <Navbar.Brand>
              <img
                src="https://i2.wp.com/laksura.com.bd/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/main_logo.png?fit=487%2C180&ssl=1"
                width="110"
                height="45"
              ></img>
            </Navbar.Brand>
          </LinkContainer>

          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav" />

          <Form className="main_form" onSubmit={submitHandler}>
            {/* <FormControl className="main_form"
                                    type="text"
                                    placeholder="Search for products"
                                    name='q'
                                    className="col-md-12 input"
                                    aria-label="Search"
                                    onChange={(e) => setKeyword(e.target.value)}
                                    
                                /> */}

            <Typeahead
              id="basic-typeahead-single"
              labelKey="name"
              onChange={setSingleSelections}
              options={products}
              placeholder="Search for products"
              selected={singleSelections}
            />

            <Button
              type="submit"
              variant="outline-primary"
              className="main-btn"
            >
              <i class="fas fa-search" style={{ fontSize: 13 }}></i>
            </Button>
          </Form>

          <Nav className="cart_pi">
            <LinkContainer to="/cart">
              <Nav.Link>
                <i
                  className="fas fa-shopping-cart"
                  style={{ marginRight: 20, fontSize: 18 }}
                >
                  <sup className="shanto">{cartItems.length}</sup>
                </i>
              </Nav.Link>
            </LinkContainer>
          </Nav>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    </header>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please add reproducible code

Comment: Like what full code??

Comment: Yes, add full code. It's better to upload it in https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Comment: Yes, I added my full code